# Use alias name in same query for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When performing a SQL Query with using an alias on a column name, I am trying to reference that alias in the same query to perform a calculation on it.

Such as:

```
SELECT QUANTITY, 
       AMOUNT, 
       Count(AMOUNT) AS CntAmount, 
       Sum(CNTAMOUNT) 
FROM   MY_TEST 
GROUP  BY QUANTITY, 
          AMOUNT
```

This query is just an example.

I thought you normally reference the query as an alias but that didn't work. Such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT QUANTITY, 
               AMOUNT, 
               Count(AMOUNT) AS CntAmount, 
               Sum(A.CNTAMOUNT) 
        FROM   MY_TEST 
        GROUP  BY QUANTITY, 
                  AMOUNT) a
```

Comment: What is the point of `SUM(CntAmount)`?  Are you sure you are not after `SUM(amount)`?

Comment: You cannot reference a column alias within the same query. I agree with Linger, this seems a bit odd. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alias in the same query, but... If you need to use an alias of an aggregate function (such as `SUM(amount) AS aggregated_alias`, `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, etc) in the same query, you must use a subquery.

Here is a sample subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
a.QUANTITY,
a.AMOUNT,
SUM(a.CntAmount) AS SUM_CNTAMOUNT
FROM (SELECT 
      QUANTITY, 
      AMOUNT, 
      Count(AMOUNT) AS CntAmount
      FROM   MY_TEST 
      GROUP  BY QUANTITY,  AMOUNT) AS a
GROUP BY a.QUANTITY, a.AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE1
AS (
    SELECT Quantity
        ,Amount
        ,count(amount) AS CntAmount
    FROM my_test
    GROUP BY Quantity
        ,Amount
    )
SELECT Quanitity
    ,Amount
    ,CntAmount
    ,SUM(CntAmount) AS Myfield
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY Quanitity
    ,Amount
    ,CntAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

As Per my knowledge you **cant directly use an alias** to perform the calculation on it.

Because if you use any name such as **'xyz'** to perform the calculation it searches into the table & if you have used alias for performing the calculation it will not permanently appears on your table.

Thats why you will get an error such as 
Column name is not exist. or invalid column name.

```
       In your case you can do like this :

       ;with CTE  as
    (
    SELECT QUANTITY, 
           AMOUNT, 
           Count(AMOUNT) AS CntAmount 

    FROM   MY_TEST 
    GROUP  BY QUANTITY, 
              AMOUNT   
    )
    select sum(CntAmount),QUANTITY,AMOUNT  as a  from  cte
group by 
GROUP  BY QUANTITY, 
              AMOUNT
```

But, if your requirement is to use only alias then you can also wrap your code into the CTE & then
you can use alias if you want

Please refer this.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935028/laravel-eloquent-query-to-get-the-result-groupbymonth)

Comment: NO this will not work. You can't have an aggregate inside an aggregate.

Comment: Please check my edited query & please reply if you get any error because it is not tested query

Comment: I don't need to test it. It will not work. You still have an aggregate in an aggregate.

Comment: sorry , @Sean Lange that I have took that many attemps to solve it

Comment: Aside from the two group by this should work. However, it is much like the other answers. There is some serious logic issue with the OP because the value of both aggregates will always be the same.