# Laravel eloquent query to get the result groupBy(month)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How to get a result with `groupBy(month('start_date'))`

So far I have

```
    $this->data['earnings'] = DB::table('documents')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id', '=', 'documents.users_id')
        ->leftJoin('users_editors','users_editors.user_id','=','users_id')
        ->groupBy(month ('start_date'), 'DESC')
        ->sum('amount')
        ->get();
```

I am trying to get earnings for all the editors `groupBy` `month` which will take month from `start_date` to have a `groupBy` on. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use (My)SQL functions you need raw statements, that are not processed and bound by PDO or, in this case, treated as a field name:

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('month(start_date)'))
```

---

In order to make it work as you expect:

```
->selectRaw('month(start_date) as month, sum(amount) as sum')

->groupBy(DB::raw('month desc'))
// or:
->groupBy('month')
->orderBy('month', 'desc')

->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts :) but this gives an error saying `unknown column DESC`

Comment: yes.. so how should I go about adding `DESC`? any idea?

Comment: put it in raw statement as well. But first, what is your expected result? Apparently there's more to do with your query to make it work as you expect.

Comment: umm yeah, correctly said. I wanted to get editors along with sum of amount for their own documents `groupBy` month. I have changed the query. I just needed to know how should do a `DESC` on `groupBy`

Comment: Check the edit. You don't want to use `sum()` method, since it will return single row. Use raw select for groupped by aggregates

Comment: Thanks that's what I did when I said I've corrected my query. Thanks so much. :) it worked.